# how can i record audio in C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was a simple way to record audio, and have it saved as an object of any sort.

My personal goal is to eventually record audio, save it to a "channel", allow for multiple channels, and play them back simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

[This project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Mp3SoundCapture.aspx) on CodeProject provides some classes for capturing audio. It uses Managed DirectX, which has been deprecated, so you might want to look into using [SlimDx](http://slimdx.org/) as a wrapper around DirectSound instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look into the OpenAL wrapper in [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/).

It should have what you need in it. The `AudioCapture` and `AudioContext` classes will collect your data, and then `AL.SourcePlay()` can be used to play multiple contexts together.